# connecting springboot application running locally to db instance running on aws VM instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2

I have written a set of APIs using springboot framework. Locally its working fine. But now I am trying to test it with the postgresql database running on ec2 instance on aws.

**NOTE:** I am not using amazon RDS services, I have created an ec2 instance and installed postgres and configured database there.

I can see this exception being thrown when I am running my springboot application locally.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:297)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
```

This is the config from `application.properties` for one of the db

```
spring.xyz.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://xyz.com:5432/xyz_db
spring.xyz.datasource.username=xyz
spring.xyz.datasource.password=xyz123
```

Am I not being able to connect because of the EC2 instance security configs ? How can I change that ?

Also it will be helpful if someone can tell me how can I make aws ec2 instance to accept the connection from only one VM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding Postgress connection-

- add below rule to security group of Ec2 instance , on which you have installed postGress
- Allow inbound traffic to postgress port from 0.0.0.0/0 and test. ( protocol- TCP, port - 5432, IP - 0.0.0.0/0)

regarding allow  from only one VM

- add security group rule to your Ec2 instance
- Allow inbound traffic from your VM IP only

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the inbound rules and facing different issue "Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections." I already looked into listen_addressess and uncommented that line. Still same issue.

Comment: What is the port number of your postgress

Comment: Check whether you have mentioned correct port number

Comment: It's the default one 5432

Comment: I am able to connect now but facing incorrect password issue. `FATAL: password authentication failed for user` I double checked the password, its correct. Any hint ? or any idea ? why its failing now